# SQL Obtener XML simple con valores nulos (FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS XSINIL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Tengo que armar un XML simple a partir de una tabla, necesito que los valores en NULL se respeten.
Tengo el siguiente código

```
Declare @Table table (ID int,Active bit,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50),EMail varchar(50))
Insert into @Table values
(1,1,'John','Smith', null),
(2,0,'Jane','Doe'  ,'jane.doe@email.com')

Select B.XML_Data
From  @Table A 
Cross Apply (Select XML_Data = (Select A.* For XML Raw)) B
```

Que arroja dos registros como resultado:

```
<row ID="1" Active="1" First_Name="John" Last_Name="Smith"/>
<row ID="2" Active="0" First_Name="Jane" Last_Name="Doe" EMail="jane.doe@email.com"/>
```

Necesito que se muestren los campos con valores null, por ejemplo, EMail="NULL"
Si agrego "ELEMENTS XSINIL" en la sentencia, cambia el formato del XML

```
Select B.XML_Data
From  @Table A 
Cross Apply (Select XML_Data = (Select A.* FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS XSINIL)) B
```

Devuelve:

```
<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ID>1</ID><Active>1</Active><First_Name>John</First_Name><Last_Name>Smith</Last_Name><EMail xsi:nil="true"/></row>
<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ID>2</ID><Active>0</Active><First_Name>Jane</First_Name><Last_Name>Doe</Last_Name><EMail>jane.doe@email.com</EMail></row>
```

Necesito obtener el XML como en el primer caso pero con valores nulos. ¿Como se podría realizar?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sino quieres tratar con XSI:NIL, siempre puedes tratar los valores null en el origen de datos.

```
Declare @Table table (ID int,Active bit,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50),EMail varchar(50))
Insert into @Table values
(1,1,'John','Smith', null),
(2,0,'Jane','Doe'  ,'jane.doe@email.com')

Select B.XML_Data
From  @Table A 
Cross Apply (Select XML_Data = 
(Select A.ID, A.Active, A.First_Name, A.Last_Name
, isnull(A.EMail,'') as Email For XML raw
)) B
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Gracias Javier. Esa es una alternativa, pero necesitaría una opción para hacer un SELECT * de tablas con una gran cantidad de campos.